# Passing variable from Program.cs to .Net Core API

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am working on a project in .Net Core which is a console application but starts an API service CreateWebHostBuilder.

In Program.cs I initialise one of my libraries that includes things such as a logging class, and I want to pass this initialised library to the API, so the API can write debug information to the same log as the main console app using exactly the same configuration.

So what I am wanting to know is, is there a way I can pass this class variable of my API  host project so it can make use of it in various controllers.

I am initialising the API service as follows in Program.cs

```
new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
{
   CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}).Start();
```

Then CreateWebHostBuilder is as follows:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    string bindAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    int portAddress = 5000;

    string engineUrl = string.Format("https://{0}:{1}", bindAddress, portAddress);

    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                 webBuilder.UseStartup<EngineAPI.Startup>();
                 webBuilder.UseUrls(engineUrl);
            });
        return host;
   }
```

Comment: The console application and API are on the same machine? Usually one is on the server and the other a client. I don't see an easy way for both to share the same log file if they aren't on the same system.

Comment: They are on the same machine, the console app hosts the API service within the same project solution. The idea is the API receives requests and queues them the console app will do some processing

Comment: Do you really need to pass the variable or share the log configs? Is logging all you need from it?

Comment: 1. Spin up a gRPC server on your ASP.net core app;
2. Initialize the gRPC client on the console app;
3. Serialize whatever you want and pass in to the server;
4. Apply it via some sort of a shared service;
5. Re-think your architecture, because it sounds messy.